# Already roasted chicken bought in store

Tags: chicken

How do I keep a store bought "hot roasted chicken" moist to eat later in the evening?

Comment: How long is later ?

Answer (score 1):

The more exposure to air it has the dryer it will become over time, so keep it in some sort of sealed container or wrap it in plastic-wrap (or foil) immediately after purchasing to lock in the moisture.